# R optim converging but abstol (accuracy) not reached

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I have an `optim` algorithm that runs several times through a projection period. I have defined an absolute tolerance that is `10^(-10)`, and a max iterations value (`maxit`) of `10000`. The accuracy `abstol` is reached for almost every step of the projection loop, except for 2 or 3 times, although the `maxit` is not reached, and the convergence value is 0 (meaning that  `optim` algorithm has converged).

Do you have any idea why the accuracy is not reached even if there is still room for iteration?

```
fun_to_optimize=function(my_variable){   
   return((life_expectancy_fun(my_variable,other_parameters)-life_expectancy_target)^2)
}
my_optim_res=optim(par=my_param,fn=fun_to_optimize,control=list(abstol=10^(-10),maxit=10000),method="BFGS")
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `abstol`?

Comment: Eventually the iteration converged due to another criterium (e.g. relative tolerance).

Comment: the `reltol` was not reached neither. I specified a higher `reltol` than `abstol`. In this example I put a `reltol` equal to `e-12`.
What other parameters may stop the iteration